# How do I pass a series to a boolean function in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to use a user-defined function to create a new column in a Pandas dataframe, which is calculated from other columns. My function calls other functions from a Python library (psychrolib) to perform the operation. I get the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I'm aware that you need to use &, |, and ! as logical operators when working in Pandas (rather than and, or, not), but since I'm using a function from a library this isn't an option. I ran down the code in the library just to be sure and found this excerpt:

```
    if (TDryBulb < -148 or TDryBulb > 392):
        raise ValueError("Dry bulb temperature must be in range [-148, 392]°F")
```

Is there another way to pass a column to a user-defined function in Pandas, or another data type I should be using? Some sample code below:

```
# Import libraries
import numpy as np
import psychrolib as psych
psych.SetUnitSystem(psych.IP) # Set unit system in psychrometric library to IP
import pandas as pd

# create example data

df = pd.DataFrame({'T_dry_bulb':[80,82,84,86,88,90]})

def processvaporpressure(t_db):
    # Calculate the vapor pressure from the a psychrometric library function
    # and then do something special to it.
    return psych.GetSatVapPres(t_db) + 0.5

df['vapor_pressure'] = df.apply(processvaporpressure,args=(df['T_dry_bulb']))
```

Comment: `df['vapor_pressure'] = df['T_dry_bulb'].apply(processvaporpressure)`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no dice. Also, I'm looking for a way to pass multiple arguments from the dataframe into the function.